# Слово Царь - оно откуда?

Tags: этимология, значение-слов

Раньше я всегда считал, что слово Царь произошло от Цезарь, но недавно наткнулся на канал Ютуб "Народная этимология" - там его выводят от шумеров. Как вы думаете это реальная версия или врет канальчик ?

Answer (score 0):

Титулы правителей Месопотамии, которые мне удалось найти: энси и лугаль. Ничего созвучного цезарю и царю там нет. Вообще, языки древней Месопотамии, насколько мне известно, очень-очень косвенно повлияли на речь наших современников. А вот латинский с "цезарем" и руский язык с "царём" восходят этимологически к индоарийскому. Уж если где и пытаться искать корни, то там.

Comment: Речь не о титуле. Эта, с позволения сказать, "теория" оперирует вавилонско-акадским словом "šarr-" (царь), сохранившемуся в некоторых личных именах. https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%80

Comment: У меня двоякое чувство, с одной стороны, вроде от цезаря, но и цезарь с другой стороны это имя ставшее позднее титулом, автор выводит название по тому же принципу - от царь в имени шумеров, с намеком на то что оно приобрело значение титула. Так что я уже начал сомневаться )

Comment: Бойтесь народной этимологии, ибо она от лукавого. Словарь Макса "наше всё" Фасмера убедительно доказывает происхождение из латыни через готский.